# how to secure my mongo db + php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using mongodb and php for my online web application. in order to interactively debug my db - I use rockmongo.

The concerns I have with rockmongo is that the admin password is in plain text in the config.php.

I like the interface of rockmogo - and frankly I am not expert in DB - so it works well for what I need - regular clean up.

What is a better way of securing my password to mongodb - for interactive web debugging.

thanks

Comment: db password in *.php file outside web root is kind of standard

Comment: Not using the admin password for CRUD access is another.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the password directly to your configuration file, you can setup an environment variable like `PASSWORD` then pull it into your config.php file with `getenv()`.

```
$ export PASSWORD=somepassword
```

and in your config.php file do something like

```
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_pass"] = getenv('PASSWORD');
```

Comment: You can use `apache_getenv()` or `$_SERVER` Superglobal to access the environment variable